# Exporting Pandas dataframe into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to export a Pandas dataframe to SQL Server using the following code:

```
import pyodbc
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import engine

DB={'servername':'NAME', 'database':'dbname','driver':'driver={SQL Native Client 11.0}'
}


engine=create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://'+'DB['servername']+'/'+['database']+'/'+['driver'])

df.to_sql(con=engine,'test')
```

The error that it shows is

> Datasource name not specified and no default driver specified

The df has 1 column and 90k-100k rows
How can I overcome this issue in order to export the dataframe (df) into SQL Server?

Comment: That's the wrong connection string to begin with - you specified `MySQL` as the driver, which is a completely different product

Comment: I have information on the driver, database name and the server name.  How do i edit the string so that it works?

Answer (score 0):

Pandas uses SQLAlchemy to connect to databases, which in turn can use PyODBC. Microsoft [recommends using PyODBC to connect to SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/python-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#getting-started).

The [SQLAlchemy docs for SQL Server](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/mssql.html#dialect-mssql-pyodbc-connect) show that the connection string should have the form:

```
"mssql+pyodbc://user:password@myhost:port/databasename?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server"
```

ie

```
engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://user:password@myhost:port/databasename?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server")
```

You can also use an ODBC connection string:

```
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL
connection_string = "DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};SERVER=dagger;DATABASE=test;UID=user;PWD=password"
connection_url = URL.create("mssql+pyodbc", query={"odbc_connect": connection_string})

engine = create_engine(connection_url)
```

You'll have to install PyODBC and the correct SQL Server ODBC driver for your operating system. The [SQL Server docs on Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-1-configure-development-environment-for-pyodbc-python-development?view=sql-server-ver15) link to the appropriate drivers for Windows, [various Linux distros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) and [MacOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos?view=sql-server-ver15)

If you have trouble saving to SQL Server, try the [SQL Server PyODBC Getting Started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/python-sql-driver-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver15) tutorial to ensure you can connect to the database